# Dropdown animation when I remove mouse

Tags: html, css, animation, navbar, dropdown

I've coded an animation for my navbar, which shows the log in form when hovered, but when I remove the mouse from it, it just disappears, I would like it to smoothly go away the same way it came, what do I have to add to the code?
[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>&#161;Servicios en un Chasquido! | Chasquido Servicios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home">INICIO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
            <div class="login-box">
              <h2>Datos</h2>
              <form>
                <p>CORREO</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">
                <p>CONTRASEÑA</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
                <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          </ul>
    </nav> 


</header>


</div>

<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="6"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/portada1.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada2.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada3.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada4.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada5.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada6.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/portada7.png" width="1900px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#carousel1" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#carousel1" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
      </a>

    </div>

  </div>

  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
.main-wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 95%;
min-width: 900px;

}

body{
margin: 0;
background: #222;
font-family: sans-serif;

}
.container{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
background: #151515 ;
 }
.logo{
float: left;
padding: 10px 0;
}
nav{
float: right;
}
nav ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
z-index:1000;
}
nav li{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 50px;
padding: 40px;
position: relative;


}
nav a{
color: lightgrey;

}
nav a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

}
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: white;
}
.menu {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
background-color: #151515;
margin-left: 50px;
}
.menu li.with-arrow {
padding: 35px 50px;
cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
color: lightgray;
font-family: sans-serif;
margin-left: 50px;
}
.menu li.with-arrow:after {
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-size: 20px;
content: '\f107';
display: inline-block;
color: yellow;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li.with-arrow:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.menu li.with-arrow:hover:after {
transform: translate(-50%, 5px);
}

.menu li {
 padding: 35px 15px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
color: lightgray;
font-family: sans-serif;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.menu li:before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
background: white;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
transform: scaleX(0);
transform-origin: right;
transition: .15s;
}
.menu li:hover:before{
transform: scaleX(1);
transform-origin: left;
}
.menu li.home:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
background: white;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
transform: scaleX(0);
transform-origin: left;
transition: .15s;
}
.menu li.home:hover:after{
transform: scaleX(1);
transform-origin: right;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
color: white;
}
.login-box{
width: 350px;
height: 420px;
padding: 80px 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 100%;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
cursor: auto;

}
.menu li:hover .login-box{
animation: load .3s forwards;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
}
@keyframes load{
0%{
    transform: translateX(25px) scale(1.6);
}
100%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
}

h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
color: #efed40;
text-align: center;

}
.login-box p
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: white;
}
.login-box input
{
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.login-box input[type="text"],
.login-box input[type="password"]
{
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
background: transparent;
outline: none;
height: 40px;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;


}
::placeholder
{
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.login-box input[type="submit"]
{
border: none;
outline: none;
height: 40px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
background: #ff267e;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover
{
background: #efed40;
color: #262626;
}
.login-box a
{
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;

text-decoration: none;

}
.login-box a:hover
{
color: yellow;

}
```

This is my entire code if you would like to see it, if it looks unprofessional or something like that, please know that I'm new to all this and it'll take me some time, I'm still in the dark here, anyway, thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the full code so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</ul>` tag, that might do something.

Comment: No, I have the </u>, I just didn't show that part. What part of the code should I add so you can see? I thought I was showing enough haha

Comment: When I looked at the image you provided, it has way more content and design than when i copy and paste your code on jsfiddle.net. Check it out: [jsfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=O0IHwba4ls)

Comment: I'll add the full code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave the `</ul>` outside of the tag you put the `<ul>` in. Your code is:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="home">INICIO</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
      <div class="login-box">
        <h2>Datos</h2>
        <form>
          <p>CORREO</p>
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">
          <p>CONTRASEÑA</p>
          <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
          <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
</nav>
```

That's not valid, and it simply doesn't make any sense. It's like doing `<nav><ul></nav></ul>`

It should be:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="home">INICIO</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
    <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
      <div class="login-box">
        <h2>Datos</h2>
        <form>
          <p>CORREO</p>
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">
          <p>CONTRASEÑA</p>
          <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
          <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Okay I fixed it, I'm new to all this so I didn't know that, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple animation you dont need the keyframes. This animation can easily create with transition. If you want to have the animation with keyframes you need to work with javascript and so you can handle the classes from li  when entering and leaving the element with the mouse. You can then give various animations to the different classes

```css
.menu li .login-box {
  transform: translateX(25px) scale(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s all linear;

}

.menu li:hover .login-box {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);

}
```

And here is the result with your Codesample:

```css
.main-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  min-width: 900px;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;

}

nav a {
  color: lightgrey;

}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #151515;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.menu li.with-arrow {
  padding: 35px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.menu li.with-arrow:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: '\f107';
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.menu li.with-arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.menu li.with-arrow:hover:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 5px);
}

.menu li {
  padding: 35px 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: .15s;
}

.menu li:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.menu li.home:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: .15s;
}

.menu li.home:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  color: white;
}

.login-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: auto;

}

.menu li .login-box {
  transform: translateX(25px) scale(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s all linear;

}

.menu li:hover .login-box {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);

}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #efed40;
  text-align: center;

}

.login-box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

.login-box input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="text"],
.login-box input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;

}

::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #ff267e;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #efed40;
  color: #262626;
}

.login-box a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;

  text-decoration: none;

}

.login-box a:hover {
  color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>&#161;Servicios en un Chasquido! | Chasquido Servicios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home">INICIO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
            <div class="login-box">
              <h2>Datos</h2>
              <form>
                <p>CORREO</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">
                <p>CONTRASEÑA</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
                <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          </ul>
    </nav> 
    </div>

</header>



 </body>
 </html>
```

The js Result: [jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/rafnixschaf/hpdo5r11/17/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=hpdo5r11)

Comment: Thanks! now it's working but I have another problem, when I hover out, the login box seems to still detect my hovering when it get's bigger, it touches my mouse and it appears again, I don't think if I expressed myself correctly, does this have a solution?

Comment: [jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/rafnixschaf/hpdo5r11/17/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=hpdo5r11)

Here is an example with javascript. The trick is we are using classes to add the animation and if we are leaving the menu we add "pointer-events: none" to the login-box. This fix the behaviour that you reopen the menu on closing

Comment: Cool, I should learn a little of javascript cause I don't even know how to open a js file, I never did it, I only worked with css and html until now